# "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples" error cause by pandas dropna()

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

[image]

I'm using the data like this. To utilize LightBGM, I used `X=X.dropna()`,to prevent later errors related to the "Input contents NaN, Infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')."

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2,
random_state=333 )
```

After that, I used train_test_split function. However,

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2348, 2356]"
```

error caused. I think the `X=X.dropna()` made the error because it elimated Unnecessary NaN values.

```
 X.shape
(2348, 15)
y.shape
(2356,)
```

So to solve the problem, the above result was printed when I printed out each "shape". But I don't know what action to take on my data.I think this is because there is a difference of about 8 in the shape values of X and y. Is there a good way to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes , there is a good way - make the rows equal.

Comment: @desertnaut Is there a way to modify the number of rows through the command?I think it would be very helpful if you could give me the search keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this error because, you are deleting `nan` values only from `X`. So, `X` has less rows than `Y`. but ideally they should be equal. So, you first have to merge `X` and `y` and then drop `NaNs`

```
train = pd.concat([X, y], axis=1, join='inner')
train = train.dropna()

y = train['target_column_name']
X = train.loc[:, train.columns != 'target_column_name']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=333)
```